# Is the image of a continuous idempotent necessarily homotopic to the original space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f$ be a continuous self-map of a topological space $X$ such that $f\circ f=f$. Is it true that $X$ is homotopic to its image $f(X)$?

Comment: No - let $X$ be any non-contractible space (say a 2-sphere) and let $f$ be a constant map. Maybe you want more assumptions?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't require $f$ to be homotopic to identity, the answer is surely no (the constant map provides a counterexample, as mentioned in the comments). If you do, inclusion $f(X) \hookrightarrow X$ and $f$ itself $X \to f(X)$ provide homotopy equivalence.